# How to count the number of times a formation in a basketball game is used

Tags: combinatorics, probability-theory, problem-solving

I am trying to find the percentage of games played with man to marking for a basketball league. There are two types of marking: zone (Z) and man marking (MM). If there are 10 teams such that each play each other twice, there are a total of 90 games. Each team plays a home leg and an away leg, for a total of 18 games a season. If I want to find the percentage of games played with MM across the league, can I count the number of MM games over the home legs and divide by 90? or do I need to count the 18 games played with MM for Team A, then Team B, then Team C, etc, then divide by 180?

Comment: In a given game, can one team use MM and the other use Z?

Comment: Both teams can use MM, ZZ, or any combination.

Comment: Then what is an MM game? If it means at least one team used MM, then using the first method could give you 100% even though MM was only used 50% of the time. So use the latter method.